# SDL_RenderPresent не работает в нити

Tags: c++, sdl

В нити в цикле вызывается `SDL_RenderPresent`, но не отображает на окно. В случае без использования нитей все работает нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите файл SDL_render.h в составе фреймворка. Там имеется такая запись на 44 строке:

```
These functions must be called from the main thread.
See this bug for details: http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1995
```

Если так, то SDL_RenderPresent может запускаться только в основном потоке.

Comment: А как тогда лучше распараллелить? События надеюсь могут в треде обрабатываться?

Comment: @Igoryan К сожалению не искушён в sdl, но думаю, что - да, безусловно. Баг с графикой касается именно связки с OpenGL, тогда как для событий ситуация проще. Кстати, в Qt аналогичная ситуация в том числе и просто при рисовании виджетов - можно только в основном или как его ещё называют графическом потоке производить рендеринг.

Comment: В sdl не как ( Поэтому я ушел на OpenGL

Comment: @egordorichev не подскажете как на OpenGL это сделать?

Comment: С помощью SDL создаешь OpenGl окно, рендеришь в него... впрочем, лови ссылку http://ivan4b.ru/simple-sdl-opengl-program-tutorial

Comment: @egordorichev фукнции glFlush() и SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window) из примера отправил выполняться в тред, опять же вижу только скрин экрана

Comment: Ну, ты хоть знаешь, что эти функции делают? Их надо вызывать уже после отрисовки.

Comment: Там полностью валидный пример, не надо менять функции местами, работать не будет.  Вот, посмотрите по OpenGL: http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/